# GetQueuedCompletionStatus - how to identify the “type” of the finished task?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winsock, winsock2

Can you please tell me, when a ready task appears in the completion port queue, then retrieving it using the GetQueuedCompletionStatus function, how do you know if this ready task is for reading or writing?

Comment: You can use the `OVERLAPPED` structure of each operation to distinguish them.

Comment: you get pointer which you pass to I/O (in case win32 api this is `POVERLAPPED`) back from packet. based on this you can know all what you save at this place

Comment: @RbMm, I cannot figure out how to initialize the members of the structure (WSA)OVERLAPPED, if there is written in every member - Reserved for internal use.

Comment: @Optimus1 - but `OVERLAPPED` can be part of larger structure, and this already - your own structure, where you can store type of I/O operation (read, write, etc), pointer to object which containing file handle on which you do I/O, pointer to memory buffers, etc. if use native api - here much more easy and clear - you simply pass pointer (your own) to I/O request, it saved in kernel (inside IRP) and returned to you back, when I/O completed. win32 layer union this pointer with pointer to iosb (called overlapped)

Comment: @Optimus1 - and so what ?  you pass pointer to `OVERLAPPED` inside your larger structure and get it back. that you can got pointer for your structure by `static_cast` (if you inherit form overlapped) or `CONTAINING_RECORD` (if your structure have this as member). by fact what i say - the same as and in remy answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach is to write a struct that either derives from the Win32 `(WSA)OVERLAPPED` struct, or has a `(WSA)OVERLAPPED` as its 1st data member. Then you can add other data members to your struct to identify its task, track its status, etc as needed.

You can then allocate an instance of your struct for each I/O operation, populating it as needed, and passing a pointer to it as an `(WSA)OVERLAPPED*` pointer to your chosen I/O function.

When the I/O completion comes back, you can typecast the provided `OVERLAPPED*` pointer into a pointer to your struct type to access its members.

For example:

```cpp
enum MY_OP_TYPE { opReading, opWriting };

struct MY_STRUCT : OVERLAPPED // or WSAOVERLAPPED
{
    MY_OP_TYPE opType;
    // other data members as needed...

    MY_STRUCT()
    {
        Internal = 0;
        InternalHigh = 0;
        Offset = 0;
        OffsetHigh = 0;
        hEvent = NULL;
        // other initializations as needed...
    }

    ~MY_STRUCT()
    {
        // cleanups as needed...
        // free hEvent if it is a (WSA)Event object...
    }

    // other methods as needed...
};
```

```cpp
MY_STRUCT *ms = new MY_STRUCT;
ms->opType = opReading;
ms->hEvent = ...; // depending on which I/O function you are using, this could be a (WSA)Event object, or a pointer to opaque app data, etc...
// other assignments as needed...
...

if (IoReadingFunction(..., static_cast<OVERLAPPED*>(ms), ...) == FALSE /* or SOCKET_ERROR */)
{
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
    // or
    // if (WSAGetLastError() != WSA_IO_PENDING) 
    {
        ...
        delete ms;
    }
}
...
```

```cpp
OVERLAPPED *ov;
...

GetQueuedCompletionStatus(..., &ov, ... );
if (ov)
{
    MY_STRUCT *ms = static_cast<MY_STRUCT*>(ov);
    // use ms as needed...

    switch (ms->opType)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

    delete ms;
}
```

Comment: I cannot figure out how to initialize the members of the structure (WSA)OVERLAPPED, if there is written in every member - Reserved for internal use.

Comment: If using C++ you could also create a polymorphic type that contains/derives from OVERLAPPED and skip the type testing through the enum. Simply cast the LPOVERLAPPED to your polymorphic type and invoke a virtual Process() member.